# Read Data from 2D JSON Object

Tags: java, arrays, json

I'm trying to read data from the following json object in Java HTTP post. I'm first converting it to string then json object to read the data.

```
{
    "entry": [
        {
            "id": "1306487646057992",
            "messaging": [
                {
                    "message": {
                        "mid": "mid.1486361982003:2ed6c8ae51",
                        "seq": 12412,
                        "text": "hi there 8"
                    },
                    "recipient": {
                        "id": "1306487646057992"
                    },
                    "sender": {
                        "id": "1374961642574944"
                    },
                    "timestamp": 1486361982003
                }
            ],
            "time": 1486361982072
        }
    ],
    "object": "page"
}
```

**Java Code**..

```
// Read from request
StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
BufferedReader reader = request.getReader();
String line;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    buffer.append(line);
}

String data = buffer.toString();
JSONObject row = new JSONObject(data);

JSONArray rows = row.getJSONArray("entry");
JSONArray first = rows.getJSONArray(0);
System.out.println("first array is "+first);
```

When I run the code I keep getting the following exception

```
org.json.JSONException: JSONArray[0] is not a JSONArray.
```

I'm trying to access the sender id & text field "hi there 8" Can't understand where i'm going wrong..Please Help..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can clearly see from what JSON you have given that `entry` is `JSONArray`but first entity inside this array is not `JSONObject`, it is simple a `JSONObject` beacause of which you are getting the error.

As error says `org.json.JSONException: JSONArray[0] is not a JSONArray`

`JSONArray[0]` is not `JSONObject` its actually a `JSONObject`.

```
JSONArray first = rows.getJSONArray(0);
```

Above line is causing the error because the returned object is `JSONObject` not `JSONArray`. So change it to,

```
JSONObject first = rows.getJSONObject(0);
```

Further to access `message text` and `sender id` you can the following,

```
JSONObject messageObject =  rows.getJSONObject(0).getJSONArray("messaging").getJSONObject(0);
String text = messageObject.getJSONObject("message").getString("text");
String senderid = messageObject.getJSONObject("sender").getString("id");
```

Comment: @Lucy try now i missed `{` in `entry: [ { id`, now it will work fine. `rows` contain a `JSONObject` instead of `String`.

Comment: Let me know if it works for you which i suppose to work.

Comment: yes it's working...but how do i further access sender.id & message.text??

Comment: @Lucy you can see the answer for your query, but you should follow [when someone answer your question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)